# date_field_tag, how i set up a default date? [Ruby on rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, default, datefield

I wanted to set a default date, the actual date for example, how i set it up?

`<%= date_field_tag(:datetime_ida, value = nil, options = {})%>`

Also how can i set up a default value in a combo box

```
<%= select_tag :children_quantity, options_for_select([['0 Children', 0], ['1 Children', 1], ['2 Children', 2], ['3 Children', 3], ['4 Children', 4], ['5 Children', 5]], 1) %>
```

and by the way, what's the difference between date_field_tag and the date_field?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this out:

```
  <%= date_field_tag(:datetime_ida, Date.today)%>
```

pass the default date as second parameter.

```
   you correctly set the default value of combo box as shown in your question.
```

Comment: main question was totally answered, I was still hoping someone else answered me the select_tag question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use date_select with :default

Comment: Date_select returns me an array, date_select_tag returns me a date, which is what i need.